# During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139

Tags: c++, string, crash, mingw

I'm a student starting to learn **C++** by myself and I have come across a problem when trying to work with `string`

This is my test code (the one that isn't working)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myString;

    cin >> myString;
    cout << myString;

    return(0);
}
```

When I tried to run it, the program just ended and exited **before I can input anything**, and this is the result when I tried to run from `gdb`

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\DANIEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\sandbox.exe
[New Thread 15036.0x31bc]
[New Thread 15036.0x2db4]
[New Thread 15036.0x2628]
[New Thread 15036.0x2280]
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
(gdb)
```

When I tried to make the file and run it from cmd

`g++ sandbox_string.cpp -o sandbox_string`

(I added the _string to separate from the _int makefile, the program is still the same)

I got this error:
[Entry point not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUbFq.png)

After a trip round Google I believe that this problem is related to *missing DLLs*. How can I know what dll(s) I'm missing and is there a way to make sure I have every dlls ?

**There are some points I would like to mention:**

• I'm acknowledged that this may be a duplicate to [Why are all my C++ programs exiting with 0xc0000139?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969123/why-are-all-my-c-programs-exiting-with-0xc0000139), but that provided no solution other than downgrading GCC. I tried that and it didn't work. Also in that question someone mentioned about *missing DLLs*, but provided no further solution.

• If I tried to `cin` an integer for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myString;
    cin >> myString;
    cout << myString;
    return(0);
}
```

It works fine, I can input and the program would output then exit normally:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\DANIEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\sandbox.exe
[New Thread 9120.0x35ac]
[New Thread 9120.0x2c4c]
[New Thread 9120.0x390c]
[New Thread 9120.0x32c0]
7
7[Inferior 1 (process 9120) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

• My compiler is *MinGW*, this is my MinGW installer screenshot with (hopefully) every details you need
[MinGW Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRiz3.png)

• I'm using *Atom* - a text editor, with a plugin to compile and run C++ code (called "gpp-compiler") because I find it comfortable to stick with one text editor instead of using IDEs, **but**, if you think there's something else I should be using, please let me know.

• I'm not new to programming but I'm (very) new to C++ so please pardon me if there is any silly mistake, also this also means that I greatly prefer **simple answer/solution if possible**. But I will have no problem with complicated answer that's accompanied by a proper explanation.

Thanks

Comment: _"If I tried to cin an integer for example, it works fine:"_ I'm confused. Obviously the program runs long enough to wait for input (because when you enter `7` you get `7` back and everything's fine). So where is your input in the first example? These cannot be the same programs.

Comment: "MinGW" encompasses a **huge** variety of versions and configurations. Please be specific about your toolchain.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have edited my question with more information:
• The first example program exited before I can input anything
• I took a screenshot of my MinGW installer which hopefully includes version number and such

Thanks

Comment: Please include relevant details as text, not links to images.

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by switching to CygWin64, thanks anyway. I s there anyway I can close this question or mark it as solved without picking a answer because none of which helped me ?

Comment: Opinion differs, but I recommend leaving it open and leaving an answer of your own explaining what you did. It's not a full solution but it _is_ a workaround and may help others. Someone might come along in the future and provide a better alternative for future visitors.

Comment: Ooh, well, actually cos this is closed as a duplicate you can't leave an answer, so I guess just leave it as it is :)

Comment: The original issue might be this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668003/the-procedure-entry-point-gxx-personality-v0-could-not-be-located

Answer (score 3):

The code seems to have no errors. but as it mentioned above this has been a compiler issue so switching to **Cygwin** from **MinGW** has solved the error.

The error code 0xc0000139 appears when mis-configured, important files gone missing or damaged. so switching in to a totally different compiler has solved the problem.

Comment: I noticed that this code will work somewhere else but not my computer, is there any reason you think maybe the cause. Because I tried downgrading and it still doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Try adding for the "cin" this code (getline (cin, mystr);)

`cout << "What's your name? ";
  getline (cin, mystr);
  cout << "Hello " << mystr << ".\n";`

Comment: I tried that too but still didn't work, however I fixed the problem by switching to cygwin