# CMake header only dependency

Tags: c++, build, cmake, header-files, catch-unit-test

I am having some trouble running a simple test with catch2 using CMake. Since catch is header only I got the impression that it is easily dropped into any project so i thought I'd just include it like a normal header file.

Project structure:

```
-build
-external
    -Catch2
        catch2.hpp
 CMakeLists.txt
 tester.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Test VERSION 1.0.0)

include_directories(external)

enable_testing()
add_executable(tester tester.cpp)
add_test(Tester tester)
```

tester.cpp:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "Catch2\catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE( "1 is 1" ) {
    REQUIRE( 1 == 1 );
}
```

Output:

```
0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.03 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - Tester (Exit code 0xc0000139
)
Errors while running CTest
```

Obviously the test should pass, but it does not. Since I am a beginner both in the realm of CMake and catch2 I am having a hard time to pinpoint the issue. What I can say for certain is that `catch.hpp` is found and there is no linker errors, it just return some error code.

I looked around and found this:

[CMake Header from library not found when implementing in catch test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51695225/cmake-header-from-library-not-found-when-implementing-in-catch-test-case)

But it has no answers, and the author does not seem to have the same problem anyway.

This is how I build and run the tests (standing in the build directory):

```
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" && mingw32-make && ctest
```

Any help is appretiated :)

Comment: This is likely caused by a faulty environment (`MingGW`). Your code and project configuration are both correct. This might give you some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847967/during-startup-program-exited-with-code-0xc0000139

Comment: @thomas_f Alright, i removed catch and just played around with mingw and apperently i get the same error just by using std::string. I tried using cygwin instead but i did not manage to make it work with cmake. I then switched to generating a visual studio project (which i was avoiding from the start because i did not want to develop in an IDE) but i found out that i can just use msbuild to build the executable from the generated project and it works like a charm with catch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i removed catch and just played around with mingw and apparently i get the same error just by using `std::string`. Someone said that it has to do with missing DLL files. I ran dependency walker on the executable and indeed a bunch of DLLs was missing. I didn't now what to do or where to get these so i ditched mingw and tried the cygwin approach.

But using cmake with cygwin i did not find any compatable generators for my development environment (windows).

I then switched to generating a visual studio project instead (which i was avoiding from the start because i did not want to develop in an IDE). But i found out that i can use msbuild to build the executable from the generated visual studio project and it works like a charm, with catch.