# Install via pacman to specific version of Python

Tags: python, msys2

The default Python version for MSYS2 seems to be 3.8. I need to use 3.7 at the moment because I have to use PyInstaller and it is not currently compatible with 3.8 in MSYS2. I can download the earlier version of Python from http://repo.msys2.org/ and install it using pacman. With a fresh install of MSYS2 I run the following commands:

```
pacman -S glib2-devel
pacman -U python-3.7.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
pacman -S python-pip
pacman -S python-setuptools
```

If I try to run a python script I am met with an error:

```
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

This is due to the fact that everything installed after Python is actually installing in the default Python 3.8 location rather than 3.7:

```
C:\msys64\usr\lib\python3.8\site-packages
```

If I copy and paste the contents of site-packages into Python 3.7 and then try running a script I get the error:

```
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

Which is supposed to be resolved via `libffi`, which was installed prior to Python, but likely does not go to a location that 3.7 can recognize?

Is there a way to set a specific version of Python as the default in MSYS2? Perhaps a path that can be set in the .bashrc file? I tried to set PYTHONPATH in there to Python 3.7 but it didn't make a difference as to where the packages ended up being installed to.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following URL...

https://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/

Look for the version of the package you need and download it.  Use

pacman -U pkgname

To install it...

The reason I know this is because gcc11 on MSYS is non-functional... it produces programs which crash and say
"During startup your program exited with code..." mentioned here:

[During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847967/during-startup-program-exited-with-code-0xc0000139)

The only workaround is to downgrade to the previous compiler which does work or use clang, which was not an option for me.

Comment: I highly doubt MSYS2 would've released an obviously broken compiler. You might have incompatible dlls in PATH and/or `C:\Windows`. Try running [`ntldd -R my_program.exe`](https://github.com/LRN/ntldd) and looking at the dlls it prints. If any of them exist in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, but are loaded from elsewhere, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use an old version of Python is probably possible, but I think it will be very difficult. You would need to make sure all the other installed packages are compatible.

I am using PyInstaller with Python 3.8 in MSYS2 without issues. I would recommend trying to work through any issues with that, instead of trying to use older versions of packages.