# C++/mingw-gcc-g++ string declaration error

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw

I am using g++ to compile a very simple c++-program with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe
```

My code:

```
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string a;
    return 0;
}
```

[Windows 10 | mingw-gcc-g++ 6.3.0-1]

When I try to run the created main.exe, I get the exit code: 3221225785.
gdb returns:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x401464
Starting program: C:/[...]/main.exe
[New Thread 14272.0x1238]
[New Thread 14272.0x548c]
[New Thread 14272.0x42fc]
[New Thread 14272.0x3db4]
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
```

I know that the error is caused by declaring the string in combination with g++. If I use clang++ to compile the code, everything works just fine.
Does anyone know what exactly causes this error, how I could find out myself or even how to fix it?

---

I found this 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969123/why-are-all-my-c-programs-exiting-with-0xc0000139), but if its possible somehow, I would prefer to not downgrade mingw-gcc-g++. The dependencywalker is not up to date 
and only returns false negatives as far as I know because it cannot handle MS API-sets.

---

[Edit] Small addendum:

I get the same error declaring a std::vector, std::set or std::map, but std::array for example works without problems.
Do I use a deprecated library or something?

Comment: If you get away with array, but not vector or strings, it must have something to do with memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I found out that static linking the standard library with -static-libstdc++ fixes the problem for me.
So I think it is a linker error only arising when dynamically linking a library - perhaps caused when using some kind of memory allocation?