# why can't I work with strings in c++ vscode?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

I am unable to run a code as simple as the following. Everything works fine if I am not working with strings. I get an error-  `exited with code=3221225785 in 2.131 seconds`. I've tried updating my **MinGw compiler**. Does not work even if I use compile and run extension on **vscode**.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
  std::string a="world";
  std::cout<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808442/vs-code-c-exited-with-code-3221225785

Comment: Try ruling out Visual Studio Code by compiling your test application manually in a command prompt. And running it from the command prompt so VSCode is not involved at all.

Comment: As you mention MinGW, I assume you are on windows. So what might happen is that the compiler using the headers of MinGW and links again the c++ runtime library provided by the microsoft or the other way round. And those are not ABI compatible.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but... In your compiler `bin` directory, find following `.dll`s: `libgcc...`, `libstdc++...`, `libwinpthreads...` (the names can wary upon compiler distribution) can copy them to the directory where your `.exe` is.

Answer (score 0):

it is really frustating to handle your systems setup, especially if you want to start to learn coding.
My rescue called: build system. I'm using [cmake](https://cmake.org) with this [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html).

But first thing first, for your special question, what you'll need are following workspace:

```
working_directory
   |--build/
   |--src/test_code.cpp
   |--src/CMakeLists.txt
```

with your code (I name it `test_code.cpp`):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
  std::string a="world";
  std::cout<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

and `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)
project(testSomething)
add_executable(test test_code.cpp)
```

and run following in `/build` directory:

```
> cmake ../src
> make
> ./test
```

Of course you'll need to install cmake first.
I think, directly using a build system in a tutorial helps you take care of your system setup, so usually those build system could find your installed compiler, linker etc. without you telling it explicitly. (So its a kind of vodoo magic :)).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVsnU.jpg)

I tried the same, but I'm getting proper results in the terminal.
I think you have not added 'mingw' to the environmental path.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ5Xc.jpg)